# Miktex: enable installing packages on the fly from command line

Tags: miktex

Is it possible to enable the option `install packages on the fly` from the command line, i.e. without interacting with the npm gui?

This would be useful for setting up miktex on CI services such as appveyor.

Comment: I think that is the default behavior of MikTeX. Maybe you have to have write permissions for it to work. Which system are you in? Windows?

Comment: The default behavior seems to be "Ask me first", which triggers a graphical prompt to confirm installation. This cannot work with appveyor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the `[MPM]AutoInstall` value:

```
initexmf --set-config-value [MPM]AutoInstall=1
```

`1` means: install without asking the user. Other possiblie values are:

- `0`: turn off automatic installation
- `2`: ask the user